# ALT+left-arrow & ALT+right-arrow not working in tmux (zsh) on Mac OSX

Tags: keyboard, zsh, tmux

I've configured my zsh to use ALT and left/right arrows to word left/right using the following in my `~/.zshrc` file, however when I open a tmux session it doesn't work and just outputs 'D' or 'C'…

```
bindkey -e
bindkey '^[^[[C' forward-word
bindkey '^[^[[D' backward-word
```

Can anyone help my get this working?

Comment: What do you get if you execute `cat` and then press `ALT+R-ARROW` / `ALT+L-ARROW`?

Answer (score 0):

Your escape sequences seem off. Try this instead:

```
bindkey -e
bindkey '^[[1;3C' forward-word
bindkey '^[[1;3D' backward-word
```

As mpy suggested in a comment, you should run `cat` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to be sure of the correct sequence.